# echo php variable and html in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I am playing around with wordpress and wondering, why this line of code works:

```
echo "<a href='....'>$name</a>";
```

I learned it this way:

```
echo "<a href='....'>".$name."</a>";
```

Is there something special defined in WP to make this work?

Comment: Nothing to do with WordPress. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, there are two types of `String`.

The first type uses the single quotes, as follows.

```
$val = 'this is a simple string';
```

The second type is as follows:

```
$val = "This is a not so simple string";
```

With the latter type, any variables included in the string will be resolved to their values, so:

```
$val = "Hello there";

$message = 'Dave says $val';
// Literally equals: Dave says $val

$message2 = "Dave says $val";
// Literally equals: Dave says Hello there
```

There are lots of other differences, which you can read about [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).